# What is the fastest method for specific bit operations between two bytes?

Tags: java, byte, bit, xor

I have two java byte variables, lets say

```
a = 00010011 
b = 01101101 (in binary form)
```

Suppose that I have a third byte

```
c = 11001000
```

where its bits will work as an indicator to select between two operations (XOR/XNOR).

e.g. if c[i] = 1 then I select to XOR a[i]^b[i] and if c[i] = 0 I select to XNOR these values.

In this example the resulted byte will be

```
d = 01001001
```

What is the fastest method in Java to achieve such a result?

Comment: What did you try so far, and why do you think it's too slow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
d = a ^ b ^ ~c;
```

or

```
d = ~(a ^ b ^ c);
```

or

```
d = ~a ^ b ^ c;
```

The `^` has the property of flipping bits set to 1 and leaving bits set to 0.  If you use `~` to flip that value you get flip for 0 and unchanged for 1.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know whether it is the fastest, which I assume is a silly question, as it's a bitwise operation only, but this will work:

```
(a XOR b) XNOR c
```

which is same as:

```
~(a ^ b ^ c)
```